# How should I troubleshoot a Blender video edit that is rendering without audio

Tags: rendering, video, audio

So I have a video I spent a couple hours editing cutting and splicing segments in Blender.  The audio works when I hit play in the sequencer, however, when rendering the video I have no audio in the final result.  I have my output set to MPEG-4 with MP3 Audio Codec, volume is correct on each segment and is set to 1.0 in output, I have sequencer checked in the post processing panel.  I have tried packing and unpacking external data but have had no progress.  What could I be missing?

Comment: Update: after closing and re-opening the project I lost all audio in sequencer as well.

Comment: SOLVED: not sure how it happened but my Audio clips lost contact with their source MP4.   I had to individually select each audio clip and re-attached the source by the "load sound file" button in the audio clips strip/source panel.  I hope this helps someone down the road.